AD RMS unable to select existing certificate during configuration
I am having problems configuring AD RMS. I have imported a certificate on the machine, but the wizard cannot locate it.
The certificate I have is not renewed, but I think I should still be able to see it. What do you think it could be due to? The account with which I am installing has local and domain administrator permissions.
The system is Windows Server 2016 in a laboratory environment.
AD RMS Error
Kind regards

The certificate I have is not renewed you mean it is expired?
